# Can I shrink this three-pulse-generating circuit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I guess what I'm after here is a code review for my redstone.

I've set up a circuit so that when I press a button, 3 items get dispensed from a dispenser, but it seems rather large. Can anyone suggest ways I could make it smaller?

[image]

Comment: Etho has done some complicated redstone like that along with tests to show how he got to his results.. You can go and try to find his videos or if I can find it (They are dealing with Wilson, his minecraft gigapet) I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I see a pulse latch, followed by a pulse extender followed by a clock to the dispenser, you could move the pulse extender down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I started by building the minimum functional part of the circuit you showed: the comparator-based controllable clock connected to a button and dispenser. (This is in the middle of the pictured circuit.) I found that this resulted in producing too many items due to the length of the button's signal. Therefore, we need to cut off the clock *sooner*.

Because redstone logic is “OR” logic, the simplest way to stop a clock, or to stop a triggered device like a dispenser from triggering, is to send an extra signal to it — so while the output will remain ON for longer than it needs to, the only thing that matters is that it stops pulsing. That is what the repeater delay at the bottom of the picture does. You can lengthen or shorten it in order to change the number of pulses produced.

The third repeater at the top is merely used to get the signal to the dispenser; you can use any part of the right-side redstone line as the output. Similarly, the button can connect to the left-side redstone any way you like. I designed the input and output of this example circuit so that it could be covered with a flat floor, as your picture suggested you were planning to do.

---

Some general principles for designing efficient redstone circuits, which could apply in this case:

- Learn the exact connectivity rules for redstone; always pay attention to opportunities to put components right next to each other without them interfering, and know what the most compact way to get a signal from one place to another is.
- If you have a circuit that works but is built out of bulky independent modules, then look for ways to:

  - modify the output and input of adjacent stages to fit together more directly.
  - replace an entire module with a modification to another one (which is sort of what I did here).
- Make use of "don't care" characteristics. For example:

  - We don't care how long the signal to the dispenser remains ON, because dispensers don't trigger except on a rising edge (OFF to ON).
  - We don't care how long the button's signal is (as long as it's longer than the repeater delay) because the repeater signal being ORed into the output makes everything else irrelevant when it turns on. (It happens to stop the clock, but even if the clock were running there would be no effect!)

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the answer you were looking for.

You can remove the sideways repeaters from this design for a small system (3 pulses) and simply run the output line along the side of the repeater block line.

[How to generate a predetermined number of pulses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52744/how-to-generate-a-predetermined-number-of-pulses)

Comment: This is my implementation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/morax01bpnii1xg/three%20pulse%20ejector.png?dl=0

The dropper is raised to separate it from the pressure plate, and put it on the same level as the slab diodes.

The pressure plate turns on a comparator in subtraction mode, and a moment later, the comparator is switched off by the 1 delay repeater.

Using redstone, rather than blocks, allows the circuit to sit flat against the floor for easy walking, and the raised slabs allow signal to pass up, but not down, preventing signal feedback. The 3 delay repeaters then repeat the pulse.